# Liquibase 3.6.0 is failing in Oracle DB - Any workaround?

Tags: liquibase

I have a large application that uses liquibase 3.5.3. I'm testing locally 3.6.0 but it is failing. It is failing when I have to add a column in a existing table, error:

```
[ERROR] Reason: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find generators for database class liquibase.database.core.OracleDatabase,                        statement: liquibase.statement.core.CopyRowsStatement@365bfc5f
```

Any workaround? I've used 3.5.3 without issues until now.

Comment: For now, I will keep using 3.5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, but it was solved when I upgraded to LB 3.6.1.

LB 3.6.1 fixes this bug, which sounds like the cause of the problem you are experiencing: https://liquibase.jira.com/projects/CORE/issues/CORE-3200?filter=allissues